# getAdapterPosition() is not a method

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

in my new Android Project, i have the following Problem, when i want to get the current position in the RecyclerView:

> Cannot resolve method 'getAdapterPosition()'

In my other Android Studio Projects, it's work's fine.

```
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    protected TextView itemName;
    protected ImageView itemIcon;

    public MyViewHolder(View v, UserClickListener listener) {
        super(v);
        // a- A
        mListener = listener;

        itemName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rowText);
        itemIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.rowIcon);

        v.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) { mListener.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition()); }
}
```

in the build.gradle i have this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.3'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getAdapterPosition()` is part of v22, of the support library, so the only way to use it, is to upgrade it. Here you can find the [changelog](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#rev21)

Comment: Thank you. In another project, it was working with v21.

Can i set up the Android Studio to send a notification when a library has a new update? Thanks.

Comment: it's a gradle thing, more than an android-studio. you can use gradle to take always the last available version of the support library. But it is strongly discouraged

Comment: @SaschaK. Concerning android support libraries visit http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/ for updates.